# What is the meaning of $(SolutionDir)\..\..\..\

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

In the property sheet: for one User Macros, the name is OSGVE_DIR, with Value: $(SolutionDir)\..\..\..\..

What is the path of $(SolutionDir) ？ \..\..\..\.. the slashes means change to the sub directory or up directory?

Comment: `$(SolutionDir)` is a macro, it should expand to the directory that holds your `Solution.sln` file. The SOLUTION DIRectory, I think it's called...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked two completely independent questions. Below is the answer to your second one. I recommend re-asking your first one as a separate question.

---

The characters `..\` signify moving up the folder hierarchy by one level. So, if while in the directory `a\b\c\d\e\f\g\` I referenced `\..\..\..\`, I would be now looking at `a\b\c\d\` The starting `\` simply says to reference the current directory and is (usually) optional.

Comment: So, you mean: if I have a directory: a\b\c, then a\b\c\.. change the directory to a\b  ?

Comment: Exactly. Every "..\" moves up on level.